# Google Cloud Memory Store (Redis), can't connect to redis when instance is just started

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore, spring-cloud-gcp

I have a problem to connect to redis when my instance is just started.

I use:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

runtime_config:  
  jdk: openjdk8
```

i got following exception:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

after 2-3 min, it works **smoothly**

Do i need to add some check in my code or how i should fix it properly?

p.s.
also i use spring boot, with following configuration

```
@Value("${spring.redis.host}")
private String redisHost;

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    // https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quotas
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, 6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(
        @Autowired JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory
) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(newObjectMapper()));
    return template;
}
```

in pom.xml

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: I'm going to bad mouth java, but is your issue not from your java server starting? If your memstore is already up, you should not have any issue connecting to it, a good test would be to have a second instance connected to the memstore when you start your other instance and see if there is any issue.

Comment: memstore is already up. i think, maybe it's a problem with my VM instance where my JVM is running, for some reason i can't establish connection to redis. can it be network issues of VM when virtual machine is just stared?

Comment: Never had any issue of the sort with some php server. Do you have other connexion dependencies? are they up and running at the instance startup or do they also have some timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows: in short, I added the “ping” method, which tries to set and get the value from Redis; if it's possible, then application is ready.

Implementation:

**First**, you need to update app.yaml add following:

```
readiness_check:
path: "/readiness_check"
check_interval_sec: 5
timeout_sec: 4
failure_threshold: 2
success_threshold: 2
app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

**Second**, in your rest controller:

```
@GetMapping("/readiness_check")
public ResponseEntity<?> readiness_check() {

    if (!cacheConfig.ping()) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**Third**, class CacheConfig:

```
public boolean ping() {
    long prefix = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("readiness_check_" + prefix, Boolean.TRUE, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Boolean val = (Boolean) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("readiness_check_" + prefix);
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(val);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("ping failed for " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

P.S.
Also if somebody needs the full implementation of CacheConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CacheConfig.class.getName());

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public CacheConfig(@Lazy RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(
            @Autowired JedisPoolConfig poolConfig
    ) {
        // https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quotas
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, 6379);

        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfig = JedisClientConfiguration
                .builder()
                .usePooling()
                .poolConfig(poolConfig)
                .build();

        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(
            @Autowired JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory
    ) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(newObjectMapper()));
        return template;
    }

    /**
     * Example: https://github.com/PengliuIBM/pws_demo/blob/1becdca1bc19320c2742504baa1cada3260f8d93/redisData/src/main/java/com/pivotal/wangyu/study/springdataredis/config/RedisConfig.java
     */
    @Bean
    redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        final redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig();

        // Maximum active connections to Redis instance
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(16);
        // Number of connections to Redis that just sit there and do nothing
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(16);
        // Minimum number of idle connections to Redis - these can be seen as always open and ready to serve
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(8);

        // Tests whether connection is dead when returning a connection to the pool
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        // Tests whether connection is dead when connection retrieval method is called
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        // Tests whether connections are dead during idle periods
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);

        return poolConfig;
    }

    public boolean ping() {
        long prefix = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("readiness_check_" + prefix, Boolean.TRUE, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Boolean val = (Boolean) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("readiness_check_" + prefix);
            return Boolean.TRUE.equals(val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("ping failed for " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```